# Mongo complex multi sort

Tags: mongodb, sorting

I would like to know if mongo lets you do complex multi sorting and how to do it.

Imagine that you have Products with two bollean (0/1) fields "Sale" & "Focus" and a price (double).

I would like to return all products but order then by:

1- Products on Focus and on Sale

2- Products on Focus

3- Products on Sale

and inside each one of this three groups they should be ordered by price desc

Is this even doable in a single query sort?

Comment: Have you looked at [sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/)?

Comment: yes @dasdachs. And I understant how simple sorting works in mongo but in this case I have to do nested sorting. And use the AND operator  inside sort

Comment: You could try chaining `$sort` with the agreggation framework.